# NetSuite Workflows

Tags: workflow, netsuite

I am a newb creating netsuite workflows. I am trying to auto populate a field in my sales order when choosing a customer in the customer field.

My mission is to get the division/region field auto populated when the customer is chosen.

Most Appreciative,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. -- from help.

Comment: I want to have the division/region field in classification in an sales order to auto populated by the customers region when a customer is chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without a workflow.  Assuming:

- Division/Region is a custom transaction body field on the sales order
- There is a Division/Region field on the Customer record of the same data type

You can do this in the definition of the transaction body field.

- Edit the custom field
- Click on the Sourcing & Filtering tab
- Select Customer in the Source List field
- Select Division/Region in the Source From field
- Click Save

Create a new sales order.  When you select a customer, the Division/Region field will be updated with the corresponding value from the customer record.

Here's a [simple video](http://youtu.be/SiWVFVF-86g) showing how.

Comment: Hey here is a new wrench I would like to throw at this.  I can get the region using this custom field.  But Can I get the division?  if so this is exactly what I would like get.  I am not sure I can get it just doing a custom field.  Please advise.

Comment: Hey Mike, I'd like to thank you for such great knowledge, but I need your help with this one.  I noticed that by creating a "custom transaction body field" instead of using the existing "Division/Region" field on the sales order it has an impact on GL. Therefore I believe creating the workflow should serve its purpose?  Tell me what you think? and if this is possible with a workflow.